# Como usar a função find para buscar uma entrada num dicionário em Python (json)?

Tags: python, dicionário

Como usar a função `find` para buscar uma entrada num dicionário em Python (json)? Devo usar json (loads) e json (dumps)? Se eu digitar, por exemplo, "ma" o resultado da busca me mostraria "Cesar Camargo Mariano", etc..

Segue o dicionário (parte dele):

```
[
  {
    "artist": "Cesar Camargo Mariano e Helio Delmiro", 
    "tittle": "Samambaia", 
    "tracks": [
      {
        "author": "Cesar Camargo Mariano", 
        "time": "5'04", 
        "type": "track"
      },
```

Comment: Utilize a função `json.loads` para converter uma *string* JSON para um objeto Python, que considerando o trecho apresentado, será uma *list* de *dict*. Essa busca deve ocorrer em todos os valores do dicionário ou apenas em *artist*?

Comment: Prezado amigo, deveria retornar, ao menos, o nome do artista quando se digita uma ou mais letras. Por exemplo: ao digitar CE, o retorno seria Cesar Camargo Mariano(não me recordo como implementar isso). Quanto ao json.loads, OK. Outra possibilidade seria esta?: jdata = json.loads(s)
for artist in jdata:
    for key, value in artist.iteritems():
        print key, value

Answer (score 2):

Não é algo tão simples assim: quando o JSON ainda é uma string, ou seja, srializado - você pode usar o find (ele é um método de strings em Python), e achar a posição dos caractéres que você quer - mas dessa forma você não sabe nada sobre a estrutura do JSON, não vai saber se o "ma" que você encontrou é de "Camargo" que está dentro de show.[artistas].nome  ou se é numa palavra que seja chave de um dicionário dentro do json. '{"tema": "música setaneja"}  daria resultado na palavra "tema".

O correto aí é carregar o se u jso na forma de uma estrtura de dados, e aí ter uma funçao que busca recursivamente, em toda a árvore, pelos patterns que você requisitar. Uma função dessas pode te retornar o registro inteiro (ou só o valor)  -

Essas duas funções podem te ajudar: a primeira retorna todas as ocorrências em que for encontrado um "match" para o que você busca - cada uma associada a um "path" - que ter permite saber *onde* no JSON a ocorrência foi encontrada. Ela é um generator,então use com um `for` ou passe a sua chamada como argumento para `list`.

A segunda permite buscar trechos do JSON usando o "path" que é retornado pela primeira função:

```
import re

def json_find(data, pattern, path=()):
    if isinstance(data, (str, float, int, bool, type(None))):
        if re.findall(pattern, str(data)):
            yield data, path
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for i, item in enumerate(data):
            yield from json_find(item, pattern, path=path+(i,))

    elif isinstance(data, dict): 
        for i, (key, value) in enumerate(data.items()):
            yield from json_find(value, pattern, path=path+(key,))
    else:
        raise TypeError("Can't search patterns in instances of {}".format(type(data)))


def get_json_item_at(data, path):
    if not path:
        return data
    return get_json_item_at(data[path[0]], path[1:])
```

E no modo interativo, se eu coloco dados como o seu de exemplo na variável "a", posso fazer:

```
In [141]: list(json_find(a, "Mariano"))
Out[141]: 
[('Cesar Camargo Mariano e Helio Delmiro', (0, 'artist')),
 ('Cesar Camargo Mariano', (0, 'tracks', 0, 'author'))]

In [142]:
```

A saída indica que a palavra "Mariano" foi encontrada em dois lugares - uma na posição 0 da lista original, e dentro dessa na chave "artist", e a segunda ocorrência na posição 0 da lista, chave "tracks", dentro dessa, na posição 0, e na chave "author".

A função de que coloquei de brinde permite que você possa, por exemplo, a partir da localização na chave "author" conseguir "subir pela árvore" até chegar na informação do registro.

Usando o path completo, eu tenho só a string onde ocorreu o match:

```
In [142]: get_json_item_at(a, (0, 'tracks', 0, 'author'))
Out[142]: 'Cesar Camargo Mariano'
```

Mas se eu remover os últimos itens do caminho, posso pegar o registro completo:

```
In [143]: get_json_item_at(a, (0, 'tracks'))
Out[143]: [{'author': 'Cesar Camargo Mariano', 'time': "5'04", 'type': 'track'}]
```